# How can I set russian locale {'accept-language' => 'ru'} for capybara and poltergeist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, poltergeist

I use rspec, capybara and poltergeist. When I set driver and accept-language in rails_helper.rb it doesn't see russian locale (not working):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
  config.before(:each) do
    page.driver.headers = { 'Accept-Language' => 'ru' }
  end
end
```

When I run tests I get english locale. How to setup http headers to get russian locale?

Comment: Have you properly set up the I18n module so that you get the correct response when using for example `cURL`?

Comment: I use `http_accept_language.compatible_language_from(I18n.available_locales)` to set locale, where `available_locales = [:en, :ru]`

Answer (score 0):

Everythings ok for driver poltergeist.
Here is code:

```
def set_locale
  locale = if current_user
             current_user.locale
           elsif params[:locale]
             session[:locale] = params[:locale]
           elsif session[:locale]
             session[:locale]
           else
             http_accept_language.compatible_language_from(I18n.available_locales)
           end
  if locale && I18n.available_locales.include?(locale.to_sym)
    session[:locale] = I18n.locale = locale.to_sym
  end
```

If you want to use driver selenium, puts `config.i18n.locale = :ru` to test.rb environment